# No Results are shown on Eclipse Console when Karate Runner file is run as Junit Test but when file called in Command line using mvn test it works

Tags: eclipse, karate

I have the below Karate Runner File Content. When I executed this file on Eclipse, nothing is shownup on Console. Can Someone please help on this issue for me.

```java
package com.accounting.apirunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;

@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:Accountspayables", "classpath:Accountsreceivables", "classpath:company",
        "classpath:generalLedger", "classpath: SpendManagement" }, tags = {
                "~@ignore" }, plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-reports" }, monochrome = true)

  public class TestCaseRunner {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("karate.env", "SAT");

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {

        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:Accountspayables", "classpath:Accountsreceivables",
                "classpath:company", "classpath:generalLedger", "classpath: SpendManagement").tags("~@ignore")
                .parallel(1);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
        String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] { "json" }, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
        for (File file : jsonFiles) {
            jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Accounting XMLGW Regression Test Suite");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

And no Executions shown up on Junit Explorer.

[image]

Comment: yes there is no dedicated eclipse support, perhaps you will like to contribute ?

Comment: Issue fixed after I Changed Value from Junit5 to Junit4 in Run Configurations.  Thank you.